# edicion de matrices

Tags: python, numpy

Estoy escribiendo un programa que me me lea una matriz y si el valor del elemento es menor de un valor lo reescriba como cero y si es mayor del valor lo deje tal cual. Hago esto:

```python
lis=open('ej.txt','r')
A=lis.read()
A=np.genfromtxt(StringIO(A))
print A
for i in A:
    if A.all() <= 2:
       A = A*0.
    elif A > 2:
       A =A*1
A=A
print A
```

y la salida es esta, lo primero la entrada original y lo segundo la salida del programa:

```
[[ 0.    0.1   0.2   0.3   0.45]
 [ 1.2   1.4   1.6   2.8   3.92]
 [ 2.1   1.8   2.4   2.2   4.7 ]
 [ 3.2   3.4   5.1   6.2   5.22]]

[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

El programa no considera la segunda condición. ¿Podría alguien ayudarme?

Answer (score 6):

Usando el **[indexado fancy](http://claudiovz.github.io/scipy-lecture-notes-ES/intro/numpy/array_object.html#indexado-fancy)**, se puede indexar con un enmascarado booleano:

#### Código

```python
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[ 0.,    0.1,   0.2,   0.3,   0.45],
              [ 1.2,   1.4,   1.6,   2.8,   3.92],
              [ 2.1,   1.8,   2.4,   2.2,   4.7 ],
              [ 3.2,   3.4,   5.1,   6.2,   5.22]])

A[A<=2] = 0
print A
```

#### Resultado

```
[[ 0.    0.    0.    0.    0.  ]
 [ 0.    0.    0.    2.8   3.92]
 [ 2.1   0.    2.4   2.2   4.7 ]
 [ 3.2   3.4   5.1   6.2   5.22]]
```

[<kbd>Demo en ideone.com</kbd>](http://ideone.com/rCXUeN)